# Listplot of a function Sin[2 x] vs Cos[2 x] when x is real and when x is random variable?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Listplot of a function  **Sin[2 x]** vs **Cos[2 x]**  when x is real and when x is a random variable? what is the effect of phase in the plot?

Comment: Show us your *Mathematica* code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];
data = {Cos[2 #], Sin[2 #]} & /@
   RandomReal[{0, Pi}, 64];

{{ParametricPlot[
    {Cos[2 x], Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, Pi},
    PlotRange -> {{-1.05, 1.05}, {-1.05, 1.05}}],
   ListPlot[
    Table[{Cos[2 x], Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/64}],
    PlotRange -> {{-1.05, 1.05}, {-1.05, 1.05}},
    AspectRatio -> 1]},
  {ListPlot[data,
    PlotRange -> {{-1.05, 1.05}, {-1.05, 1.05}},
    AspectRatio -> 1],
   ListCurvePathPlot[data,
    PlotRange -> {{-1.05, 1.05}, {-1.05, 1.05}}]}} //
 Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### ListLinePlot

```
table1 = Table[{Sin[2 x], Cos[2 x]}, {x, Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/16]}];

SeedRandom[1]
table2 = Table[{Sin[2 x], Cos[2 x]}, {x, RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 16]}];

ListLinePlot[{table1, table2},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 Epilog -> Circle[],
 PlotLegends -> {"table1", "table2"}]
```

[image]

#### ParametricPlot

```
ClearAll[rR]
rR := RandomReal[{-.5, .5}];

SeedRandom[1]
Show[ParametricPlot[{Sin[2 x], Cos[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.2]], 
 ParametricPlot[{Sin[2 (x + (rr = rR))], Cos[2 (x + rr)]}, {x, 0, 
   2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.7, Blue], MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  PlotPoints -> 20], ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
Show[ParametricPlot[{Sin[2 x], Cos[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.2]], 
 ParametricPlot[{Sin[2 (x + (rr = rR))], Cos[2 (x + rr)]}, {x, 0, 
   2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3, Blue], MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  PlotPoints -> 1000], ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]